# Why the postman is returning a "Non-static method requires a target."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2, .net-4.6

I have a Save method in my SavesController (Web Api controller). When I tested it with postman it returned this.

```
    {
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Non-static method requires a target.",
"exceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetException",
"stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.    <InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
  }
```

My save method is this. Exception was thrown at if statement

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Save(SavesDto dto)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (_context.SavedPosts.Any(a => a.AttendeeId == userId && a.PostId == dto.PostId))
    return BadRequest("The save already exists.");

    var savedPost = new Saves
    {
        PostId = dto.PostId,
        AttendeeId = userId
    };
    _context.SavedPosts.Add(savedPost);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

I have searched through the internet.I found out that problem comes from using a null value within the LINQ. But Any method in Linq statement just returns true/false, why is it throwing this exception?

```
    public class SavesDto
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}
```

I called the Api here

```
@foreach(var post in Model)
{
<button
 data-post-id="@post.Id" 
class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right .js-toggle-save">Save ?</button
}

@section scripts
{
  <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".js-toggle-save").click(function(e)
    {
        var button = $(e.target);
        $.post("/api/saves", { postId: button.attr("data-post-id") } )
        .done(function()
        {
            button.removeClass("btn-default")
            .addClass("btn-info").text("Saved");
        })
        .fail(function ()
        {
            alert("something failed");
        })
    });
}
);
</script>
}
```

PostId and AttendeeId are not nullable

```
public class Saves
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string AttendeeId { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you use a variable in a lambda expression which is null.  It appears that the dto object is null.  So try doing this:

```
if (dto != null && _context.SavedPosts.Any(a => a.AttendeeId == userId
  && a.PostId == dto.PostId))
```

Comment: Yes dto object was null. Now Null reference exception is being thrown at next line. Any idea why dto object is null because I'm passing postId in script and thanks.

Comment: The method in the controller isn't creating an instance of the dto object to then populate it with the PostId value.  If you accepted: int PostID, instead of the dto object, then I expect it would work.